MomentJS - Create An ISO 8601 Datetime String In UTC Using Date, Time, And Timezone Variables
I have three separate variables I want to use to construct an ISO 8601 datetime string in UTC (without offsets).  The three variables are:

Date (in 2024-7-31 format)
Time (in 14:00 format)
Timezone (can be one of four values - America/New_York, America/Chicago, America/Denver, America/Los_Angeles)

The timezone of the current user (current browser + operating system) should be irrelevant.  The user can be in one of the above 4 timezones or any timezone in the world.
I've tried using:
import moment from 'moment';
import 'moment-timezone';

const startDate = '2024-7-31';
const startTime = '14:00';
const startTimezone = 'America/Chicago'
console.log(moment.tz(startDate + ' ' + startTime, startTimezone).utc().format());

The above generates 2024-07-31T14:00:00Z - which equals to 9:00 AM Chicago time on 7-31.  The time should be 2:00 PM Chicago time on 7-31.  If I change startTimezone to America/New_York, I get the same ISO 8601 result (9:00 AM Chicago time).
From the looks of it, it seems like Moment isn't taking into account the timezone I am feeding it.  How do I get Moment to take into account the timezone it is being given?

The browser could be doing that to the datetime isn't it?

Here is your code snippet.  Run it and you will see the problem immediately.


const startDate = '2024-7-31';
const startTime = '14:00';
const startTimezone = 'America/Chicago'
console.log(moment.tz(startDate + ' ' + startTime, startTimezone).utc().format());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.45/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>



Moment's warning is as follows:

Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged.

Indeed, the string you're parsing "2024-7-31 14:00" is not ISO 8601 compliant, because months are required to be two digits. (It's not RFC2822 compliant either.)
You can solve this by changing the input date to "2024-07-31".


const startDate = '2024-07-31';
const startTime = '14:00';
const startTimezone = 'America/Chicago'
console.log(moment.tz(startDate + ' ' + startTime, startTimezone).utc().format());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.45/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>



Alternatively, you can leave the input date as-is, and supply a format string to Moment:


const startDate = '2024-7-31';
const startTime = '14:00';
const inputFormat = 'YYYY-M-DD H:mm'
const startTimezone = 'America/Chicago'
console.log(moment.tz(startDate + ' ' + startTime, inputFormat, startTimezone).utc().format());
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-timezone/0.5.45/moment-timezone-with-data-10-year-range.js"></script>




In your first example, the space between the date and time should be replaced with a "T" for better ISO 8601 compliance. :-)
